# CSS, words wrap automatically

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

CSS, words wrap automatically. How to do this?

I want to let words like:

```
O:
Which is the most horrifying thing/disease you have seen in your medical career?

To:
Which is the most horrifying
thing/disease you have seen
in your medical career?
```

---

I am used `word-wrap: break-word` but display like:

```
Which is the most horrifying t
hing/disease yo
u have seen in you
r medical career?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is, if you want it to be specific width, then you have to define it.
Example:

HTML:

```
<p>Which is the most horrifying thing/disease you have seen in your medical career?</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    width: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/

The hyphen property additionaly let's you control hyphenation. To function properly, this needs a language to be defined on the parent. The easiest way would be to change

```
<body>
```

to

```
<body lang="en">
```